# How can I call a variable when it's name is stored as a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables

Hello I was wondering if there was a way of calling a variable if I had it's name as a string.
For example I have a list of names

```
    variables=["a","b","c"]
    a=2
    b=3
    c=4
```

I would like to call the variables using the strings stored in the list which storing their values in the list allowing me in essence to have a list of variables.
e.g.
        d=a[0]
I would like d to equal the value of the variable a not store the string value of a
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but there is probably a better way to do whatever you are actually trying to do. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I want to call the variable from it's string value rather than store the variables value in the list.

Comment: Maybe you want a dictionary from what I understand?

Comment: Using eval ? a=2, then using eval(variables[0]) or eval('a') both should evaluate to 2

Comment: that's just what I was looking for thanks @Skycc

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wasn't asking how to create a variable number of variables, I was asking how to call a variable from having the name of the variable stored in a string form

Comment: @thestarchyninja: the answer is *exactly the same*, wether you want to access variables or create them.

Comment: oh sorry what is the right thing to do in this situation @MartijnPieters should I delete the post or should I just leave it

Comment: Normally I'd say that duplicates have a utility in that they exist to be sign-posts to the canonical post (anyone using a Google search may find your post first, then get redirected automatically to the other post), but there are [already nearly 200 such posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1373164?lq=1), so it's up to you really.